# Azure Service Bus : Failed to create a receiver for the requested session 'session-1'

Tags: typescript, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

We have set up a session-enable azure service bus topic. This topic sends message with session IDs. We have only one client listening to this topic. When we want to create a receiver with a sessionId (we use the Azure Service Bus Javascript SDK), we have this error : `Failed to create a receiver for the requested session 'session-1'`.

Here is the code in the sender function for the topic :

```
import { ServiceBusClient } from "@azure/service-bus";

const TOPIC_NAME = "entities-changed";

export const sendToServiceBus = async (message: { [key: string]: any }) => {
    const serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient(process.env.SB_ENDPOINT);

    const sender = serviceBusClient.createSender(TOPIC_NAME);

    await sender.sendMessages({
        body: message,
        sessionId: "session-1",
    });
};
```

And the code in the listener function from the topic :

```
import { ServiceBusClient } from "@azure/service-bus";

const sbClient = new ServiceBusClient(process.env.SB_ENDPOINT);

const receiver = await sbClient.acceptSession(
    RECEIVING_FROM_TOPIC_NAME,
    RECEIVING_FROM_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME,
    "session-1"
);

// We have the error here

const messages = await receiver.receiveMessages(1, {
    maxWaitTimeInMs: 10000,
});
await receiver.completeMessage(messages[0]);
await receiver.close();
await sbClient.close();
```

Does anyone already have this issue ? Any ideas to fix that ?

**EDIT** : after some investigation, here are some feedbacks.

- According to Azure, it is not recommended to programmatically received message in Function App. In this case, it is recommended to use bindings.
- Concerning the sessions, by setting `isSessionsEnabled : true` in `function.json`, the sessions are internally managed when we receive the message.

Answer (score 0):

- Here I have a workaround where I was able to receive the message which are session enabled .
- This is achieved using the `subscribe`  function and message handlers.

```
const { delay, ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage , ServiceBusSessionReceiver } = require("@azure/service-bus");

const  connectionString = "<>";

const  topicName = "topic";

const  subscriptionName = "sub";

const  sessionId = "your session id";

  

async  function  main() {
    const  sbClient = new  ServiceBusClient(connectionString);

    const  reciever = sbClient.acceptSession(topicName,subscriptionName,sessionId,{

        maxAutoLockRenewalDurationInMs:0,

        receiveMode:"receiveAndDelete",

        skipParsingBodyAsJson:true

    });

    (await  reciever).subscribe({

        processMessage:  async (message)=>{

            console.log(`Process Message: ${message.body}`);

            },

        processError:(messageReceived) => {

            console.log(`Received message: ${messageReceived}`);

            }

        }); 
}
  

// call the main function
main().catch((err) => {
    console.log("Error occurred: ", err);
    process.exit(1);
});
```

Service Bus Before receiving the message:

[image]

Output:

[image]